# Status Code: 403, while Getting an Object that doesn't exists

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have a user - Manager with `S3Actions.GetObject, S3Actions.PutObject` assigned to it

- When I put and Object and get it, everything is fine
- When I get an Object that doesn't exists, it throws

}

```
Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 2A23D3118F9FFB08, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, S3 Extended Request ID: 3h4D2Ks9skcSab3zkV/nedmm9b8WLL+92DESbOx9xGipkH7P69QQiJLVWyDowASi
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:556)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:289)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2724)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:866)
    at com.sr.sparrow.business.xml.persist.S3Service.getInputStream(S3Service.java:58)
```

Why is it not throwing `404/NoSuchKey`?

Comment: I think you should check again , if you have permissions to list the content of the bucket. 403 is thrown when file does not exist and user doesnt have permission to list the s3 objects and 404 is thrown when file does not exist and user has permission to list the objects.

Comment: `403 is thrown when file does not exist and user doesnt have permission to list the s3 objects` , can you point me to the documentation which says it please?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=210268

Comment: Huge Help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by `user1585811`, this is the best explanation

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=210268